# How to find index of a specific value in a dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe and I know that the max value is 74 but how can I find the index values for this value.
i.e what code would I need to find this value

df[x,y] = 74
what would x and y be

Comment: Slightly flawed (in the use of `==` and floating-point), but `which(mtcars == max(mtcars), arr.ind = TRUE)` gives you the row/col. This assumes that all columns are `numeric` or `integer`, anything else will require more work/subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

```
# generate random data frame with 2 columns
df  = data.frame(A = runif(1000000), B = runif(1000000))

# maximum of column A
max(df$A)

# index of maximum of column A as vector, it works for multiple maximums as well
which(df$A == max(df$A))

# for maximum in all columns
which(df == max(df), arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted it - I think not having arr.ind =T was the problem.

Comment: Glad to help you! If there are no follow-up questions, mark the topic as solved.

Comment: Im new to this site - how do I mark it as solved? its probably obvious I just cant see it